# Delphi: Logging UI events fired by user

Tags: user-interface, delphi, logging, delphi-xe2, activity-tracing

I've been asked to put something in place into our programs in order to log somewhere what's happening on forms...

Logging something such ...clicked either this or that button, context menu, events fired on components and so on..

This mostly because we are dealing with legacy code, not quite structured unfortunately that we are adjusting/reviewing (Delphi XE10) when possible and we would like to track everything is happening (or most of it) from an user's point of view in order to 
- being able to have a lead on what the user did when something mysterious happens
- being able to review the code where necessary when we have no idea of how thing have happened
- eventually speed issues

I'm not talking about exceptions or data logging...those are properly handled.

It's just about the UI.

Do you know if there is any library that might do something similar?
If not, how would you try to achieve this?

Code examples are happily accepted (even simple such as one/more form/s with a few buttons etc)

Thanks all!!!

Comment: Be careful when you ask "do you know a library" on this site, because it's against the rules. People get awarded with additional privileges when they review/close a certain number of questions.

Comment: Oh thanks for that...i didn't think that it could have been an issue ;)

Answer (score 1):

As a lightweight solution you can use [OutputDebugString(PChar('My logtext'))](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/OutputDebugString), or [TFile.AppendAllText('log.txt','My logtext')](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.AppendAllText).

If you want fancy logging with special viewers, thread-safe, etc, you could include some special logging framework. In that case it's better search online and compare features yourself instead of asking for an opinion here.

Comment: Well, Thanks....but i know how to log something....the question was more about how to structure things, in order to build something that could be "injected" on the actual code without the necessity to go, event by event, and put some code in it....     Let's say something a little more "dynamic"....;)

Answer (score 1):

You could develop a non visual component and drop it on every form, but this would have to be a very complex component that either uses RTTI or peeks at windows messages to try to listen to what is happening to the other visual components in the form.

I see two simpler ways to do at least part of what you are asking...

### 1) Intercept calls to eventhandlers

Develop a component (somewhat simpler than the one I hinted at above) that hooks up to the events of the control classes you're interested in, logs the calls, and then forwards them to the original eventhandler procedures (if any).

Suppose you are interested in `TWinControl.OnEnter` and `OnExit`, `TButton.OnClick` and `TEdit.OnChange`...

```
TEventLogger = Class(TComponent)
Private
  Procedure Hookup(Const EventName: String; Const Component: TComponent; Const LoggingHandler: TNotifyEvent; Var Handler: TNotifyEvent);
Public
  Procedure Setup(Const Container: TComponent);
  Procedure HandleChange(Sender: TObject);
  Procedure HandleClick(Sender: TObject);
  Procedure HandleEnter(Sender: TObject);
  Procedure HandleExit(Sender: TObject);
End;

Procedure TEventLoggerHookup(Const EventName: String; Const Component: TComponent; Const LoggingHandler: TNotifyEvent; Var Handler: TNotifyEvent);
Begin
  if Assigned(Handler) Then
    Handlers.AddObject(Component.Name + ';' + EventName, Handler);
  Handler := LoggingHandler;
End;

Procedure TEventLogger.Setup(Const Container: TComponent);
Var
  i: Integer;
  c: TComponent;
Begin
  For i:=0 to Container.ComponentCount - 1 Do Begin
    c := Container.Components[i];
    if c Is TWinControl Then Begin
      Hookup('Enter',HandleEnter,TWinControl(c).OnEnter;
      Hookup('Exit',HandleExit,TWinControl(c).OnExit;
    End;
    If c Is TButton Then 
      Hookup('Click',HandleClick,TButton(c).OnClick;
    If c Is TEdit Then 
      Hookup('Change',HandleChange,TEdit(c).OnChange;
  End;
End;

Procedure TEventLogger.Procedure HandleChange(Sender: TObject);
Var
  s: String;
  i: Integer;
  e: TNotifyEvent;
Begin
  With Sender As TComponent Do Begin
    s := Name + ';Change';
    Log(s);
    i:= Handlers.IndexOf(s);
    If i <> -1 Then Begin
      e := Handlers.Objects[i];
      e(Sender);
    End;
  End;
End;
```

This is not tested, but I think you got the point. Things to keep in mind:

- Handlers is a simple `TStringList`... but you could do better with a generic `TDictionary<Key,Value>`. Of course you should create it and destroy it appropriately.
- All the listed events are `TNotifyEvents`. But you can easily overload the Hookup procedure to handle other types ov events.
- Setup must be executed when components have been already created and properties streamed in from the dfm. This may require you add some code to each form.
- This technique may (and will) backfire if your application creates controls at runtime in a dynamic way, or if it messes with eventhandlers at runtime.

### 2) Use inheritance

Derive a new class of visual component for each one used that you want to log. All you need to define for each of these is a Log method and override the specific "event" methods your're interested in. For example:

```
TLogButton = class(TButton)
private
  procedure Log(Const Event: String);
protected
  procedure Click; override;
end;

TLogButton.Click;
begin
  Log('Click');
  Inherited;
end;
```

You could then implement the Log method adding all the info you need (form and component class and name, or others). If you want to do something complex, then you will be better off delegating the log operation to a specialized class.

This is also not tested. Things to keep in mind:

- To set it up, you can just use a massive Search and Replace... to
  modify `TButton` in `TLogButton`... in both pas and dfm files (I do hope
  you are using text dfm, if not you better convert them to text).
- You'll have to add your new unit to the Interface section of all
  forms that contain controls you're interested in
- You should
  register you new classes in a custom library so as to have them
  available in the IDE, otherwise you won't be able to open your forms
  at design time.
- You have to do this for every class you're
  interested in... which can become messy if the application uses many
  different but similar classes of controls.
- You have to know the
  internals of the classes you want to log... not all methods are
  overridable... many third party libraries do not come with sources...
  it can be hell.

### Conclusions

Overall... I'd probably go with the latter solution. It is basically easier to implement on a single class of controls, and you could probably already get some very useful tracing of user activity with just a bunch of classes. The former solution is a bit more sophisticated, and could probably be extended to cover some situations... but it is harder to test throughly and it is too risky if you do not know your code base very well.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion.  Yes, my intention was to build a non visual component using RTTI to go through each control on forms and so on...  Using maybe Observers too.  I can't dedicate some time now to try and test as i'm building a logging tool on the SQL server side to log changes on tables etc..... I'll get on top of this asap hopefully... I'll let you know eventually how it goes ;)